# Searching through object in React using another object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I have something like this that works great:

```
const handleFavour = () => {
  const { developers } = state;
  const results = developers.filter(list =>
    list.uid.includes("authid")
  );
  setSearchResults(results);
  console.log(results);
};
```

But now insead of "authid" if i wanted to search using another object or array that has many authids, how do I do this search? Couldn't find anything after searching for a very long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if any element in an array matches any element in another array you could combine your current solution with `.some`.

```
const handleFavour = () => {
  const allowedIds = ['id1', 'id2'];
  const { developers } = state;
  const results = developers.filter(list =>
    list.uid.some(uid => allowedIds.includes(uid))
  );
  setSearchResults(results);
  console.log(results);
};
```

Here `.some` will return `true` if any of the elements in `list.uid` are also present in `allowedIds`.

---

Based on your situation as described in the comments it looks like you want something like this:

```
const handleFavour = () => {
  const users = [{ auth: 'id1' }, { auth: 'id2' }];
  const { developers } = state;
  const results = developers.filter(list =>
    users.some(user => user.auth === list.uid)
  );
  setSearchResults(results);
  console.log(results);
};
```

I initially thought `list.uid` was an array since you were using `.includes`, generally I'd recommend using the strict equality operator (`===`) to compare strings unless you actually want to allow partial matches, but I'm guessing in this case you don't.